# OWASP Testing Guide Equivalent for Desktop Applications

Tags: penetration-test, appsec, owasp, desktop

I was wondering if any of you know of a guide similar to the OWASP Testing Guide but meant specifically for desktop applications?

I had no luck searching the Internet.

I am looking for something that focuses on or includes blackbox testing, and preferably some sort of recognized reference.

Thank you all!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type, "where can I find a product/service that does X?" is off-topic here.